# MATLAB and python equivalent coding

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, pytorch, filtering

I have an image of size 450x620. I am applying median (3x3) and mean (35x35) filter to the image, and then subtracting the two filtered images and taking absolute value to calculate the saliency map of the source image. I have implemented in MATLAB and obtained the output. But when the same is implemented in python I am getting some values where the mean and median filtered imsges have same pixel values, thus the image have some dark patches. What are the possible reasons and solutions for the same.

**Pytorch code in Google Colab:**

```py
# Load the IR and visible images
im1 = cv.imread('/content/IR12.png')
im1 = cv.cvtColor(im1, cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
im2 = cv.imread('/content/VIS12.png')
im2 = cv.cvtColor(im2, cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
IR = torch.from_numpy(im1).double()
VIS = torch.from_numpy(im2).double()

# Apply mean filtering
base1 = cv.blur(im1,(3,3))
base2 = cv.blur(im2,(3,3))
base1 = torch.from_numpy(base1).double()
base2 = torch.from_numpy(base2).double()

# Compute detail maps
detail1 = IR - base1
detail2 = VIS - base2
#cv2_imshow(detail1)

# Apply median filtering
medIR = cv.medianBlur(im1, 3)
medIR = torch.from_numpy(medIR).double()
medVIS = cv.medianBlur(im2, 3)
medVIS = torch.from_numpy(medVIS).double()

# Apply mean filtering using a larger kernel
meanIR = cv.blur(im1,(35,35))
meanIR = torch.from_numpy(meanIR).double()
meanVIS = cv.blur(im2,(35,35))
meanVIS = torch.from_numpy(meanVIS).double()


# Compute saliency maps
salIR = abs(meanIR - medIR)
cv2_imshow(salIR.numpy())
salVIS = abs(meanVIS - medVIS)
#salIR = torch.from_numpy(salIR).double()
#salVIS = torch.from_numpy(salVIS).double()


# Compute weight maps
weightIR = salIR / (salIR + salVIS)
weightVIS = salVIS / (salIR + salVIS)

# Fuse the base and detail maps
basef = 0.5 * (base1 + base2)
detailf = (weightIR * detail1) + (weightVIS * detail2)

# Compute the fused image
fused = torch.add(basef,detailf)

#fused = torch.from_numpy(fused)

# Convert the fused image to uint8 for visualization
#fused = fused.clamp(0, 255).byte()

# Convert the fused image tensor to a NumPy array
fused_np = fused.numpy()
cv2_imshow(fused_np)
```

[image: Python Output Image]

**MATLAB code:**

```matlab
Im2 = imread('D:\ankan\IV_images\IV_images\VIS12.png');
Im1 = imread('D:\ankan\IV_images\IV_images\IR12.png');
IR = double(Im1);
VIS = double(Im2);
[m,n] = size(Im2);

kernel1 = 3;
kernel2 = 35;

meanFilter1 = ones(kernel1)/(kernel1^2);
meanFilter2 = ones(kernel2)/(kernel2^2);

base1 = imfilter (IR,meanFilter1,'conv','replicate');
base2 = imfilter (VIS,meanFilter1,'conv','replicate');

detail1 = IR-base1;
detail2 = VIS-base2;

meanIR = imfilter (IR,meanFilter2,'conv','replicate');
meanVIS = imfilter (VIS,meanFilter2,'conv','replicate');

medIR = medfilt2(IR,[3,3]);
medVIS = medfilt2(VIS,[3,3]);

salIR = abs(meanIR - medIR);
salVIS = abs(meanVIS - medVIS);

weightIR = salIR./(salIR+salVIS);
weightVIS = salVIS./(salIR+salVIS);

basef = 0.5*(base1+base2);
detailf = (weightIR.*detail1)  +  (weightVIS.*detail2);

fused = basef+detailf;
imshow(uint8(fused))
```

[image: MATLAB output]

Comment: Are you sure you are [properly saturating](https://docs.opencv.org/4.8.0/d0/d86/tutorial_py_image_arithmetics.html) your arithmetic operations?

Comment: Did you look at intermediate images? Where do these start to diverge between the two versions of the code?

Comment: @CrisLuengo I checked for the matrices generated at each step. The diversion occurs while the base1 and base2 calculation, i.e. where the first time the mean filters are used.  Like the first value in MATLAB was 200.444 and for Python it was 196.  .

Comment: @stateMachine  I have doubts about the filtering operations in MATLAB and Python which might be working differently.

Comment: Well you’re going to see small differences near the image borders because in MATLAB you use “replicate” and in OpenCV you leave it to the default “reflect”. But this will only ever affect up to a few pixels into the result, not in the middle. Compare values towards the middle of the array, where you see the artifacts in the final result.

Comment: @CrisLuengo at [230,351] Python gives 188. and MATLAB gives 192.8889. Should we consider changing the filtering process in Python other than opencv?

Comment: @CrisLuengo I have to apply a CNN after this pre-processing part which is why I am coding this in Python. Could you suggest an alternate mean and median filtering process other than opencv. I am relatively new to Python.

Comment: You could try skimage. But I think the difference is that in the Python code you apply the filtering to a uint8 image, whereas in MATLAB you convert to doubles first. OpenCV, when given a uint8 image, will do integer computations and produce an integer-valued output. The differences you see are likely caused by rounding of the operations (i.e. divide each value by 9 rounding down, then add them up, instead of adding them all up and then dividing by 9). Try casting the input arrays to floating-point before applying the first filter.